# Why does USS Discovery's saucer section spin?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, star-trek-discovery

In [Episode 4](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Butcher%27s_Knife_Cares_Not_for_the_Lamb%27s_Cry_(episode)) of *Star Trek: Discovery* we see that when Captain Lorca orders [Black Alert](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/171111/83101) to activate the Spore Drive, the two parts that form the saucer section start to spin, the outermost in a direction and the innermost in the opposite one<sup>1</sup>.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

Is it explained somewhere the (fictional) technical reason of this, apart being seemingly related to the aforementioned Spore Drive?<sup>2</sup>

I'm also interested in background information if it is available, since, AFAIK, no explanation was given in the show (yet).

---

<sub>*1. Also, when the "jump" actually starts, the whole ship seems to spin around the front-rear axis, but maybe this is just a visual effect to denote a FTL inception, pretty much like Starships seemed to be "stretched" when entering Warp Speed in previous series.

2. Except, maybe, being the ultimate weapon against the dreaded Giant Space Pizza Monster?*</sub>

Comment: The only hint we have so far is a reference to "excess energy cavitation" -- the implication seems to be that the spin stabilises the ship in transit, possibly offsetting, from an internal perspective, the axial spin we see as an effect. This is another question that I expect we'll need another week or two to answer clearly, though.

Comment: I think the front-rear axial spin is simply the ship twisting itself through several dimension as it jumps. Since those inside the ship are part of that twist, they don't notice it.

Comment: What is stranger though is that its not the whole sections moving (the windows on the outside part are completely unmoving. oO

Comment: @Thomas I suppose that it is for structural integrity purposes; you need a fixed part to provide a supporting structure that also serves the moving parts.

Comment: This could tie into the helical deformation of the crew of the Glenn. The boarding party was able to diagnose the deformation quickly, as if the injuries were not completely unknown or unexpected.

Comment: @KeithPayne those injuries were because they came out too near to a strong gravity source. It is possible that such a thing happened before already with different drive sources (I only say the singularity in romulan warp drives...I could see such drive source ideas bringing similar results in deformity there as the "source" of the deformity is the same...and if the federation also experimented into that direction....)

Comment: I don’t know how plausible this is, but *mumble mumble* energy + spinning saucer put me in mind of a flywheel: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel_energy_storage

Comment: It could be a scheme to improve hull armor. Hard to lock on to previous damage with a second phasor blast when the thing keeps moving. Stick a matter replicator under the neck and you can repair holes as they swing by.Only draw back is, well, ever lived in an apartment with  neighbors above you? Yeah. I hope they keep this oiled.

Comment: It has to spin and lock 7 positions into place before it can engage the spore drive.

Comment: Speculation on the out-of-universe reason: Someone involved in the show's conception saw one of those novelty Enterprise-shaped pizza cutters cutting through a mushroom-topped pizza and thought the movement looked too cool to use on just real world fungi.

Answer (score 3):

Well since rotating saucer is actually called "excess energy cavitation system" and we know its somehow related to the spore drive. My Guess: Cavitation is the formation of vapour cavities in a liquid, small liquid-free zones ("bubbles" or "voids"), that are the consequence of forces acting upon the liquid. And excess energy is probably something like excess heat and that is the heat which is delivered to or withdrawn from the environment by an mixing process. So maybe there are similar effects when jumping back to normal space or while inside the Network maybe something like an rest energy on the hull that needs to be delivered to the surrounding space since it would otherwise harm the hull with an effect like the cavitation on modern turbines. The spinning of the jump itself is just an in universe optical illusion if you look at the lorca maneuver we get one shot from inside the discovery while jumping and there it doesn't spin around. The Idea of the Sporedrive itself is kind of strange but an organic quantum entanglement drive why not? There are many examples even today where nature found ways we can't rebuild with our technologies and we've seen in StarTrek living Crystals, organic space lifeforms which are able to go to warp, beings of pure energy and even gods like the Q so why shouldn't there be something like the Mycelnetwork?^^

Comment: You've provided quite a bit of speculation, is there any chance there are some canonical sources to help provide a more canon backed answer?

Answer (score -1):

It could have more to do with keeping the ship stable like a spinning wheel being difficult to turn.  And the inner section offering some counter rotation so there's no counter spinning of the ship.

Comment: Can you cite any canon sources to back this up?

Comment: @LogicDictates - Spoiler, he could not.